# How can I run a build from another gulpfile?

Tags: node.js, gulp

As part of my build process, I need to run a gulp build on a submodule from another project. I know I can use "require('path/to/other/gulpfile.js')", but it doesn't seem like gulp does anything to handle task name collisions. Both gulpfiles have a "build" task.

Is there a way to rename an already-defined gulp task at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply want to use a shell command to call gulp in a separate process. You can use [gulp-shell](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-shell) to do that

```
gulp.task('main-task', shell.task([
    'gulp submodule-task'
], {
   cwd: './path/to/submodule' 
}))
```

Comment: I decided to just make another task called `"build.deps"` which executes the other build using `child_subprocess`. I then made my `build` task dependent on `build.deps`.